# Difference between path helper and [action, controller] in button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I wanted to add another action to a controller. So I defined the action in my controller, added a button to activate it and added it to routes.rb.

orders_controller.rb

```
...
def shipped
...
end
...
```

routes.rb

```
resources :orders do
  put :shipped, on: :member
end
...
```

view/orders/edit.html.rb

```
...
<%= button_to 'Ship', order_shipped_path, method: :put %>
...
```

However when I tried to view /orders/1/edit I got this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"shipped", :controller=>"orders"}
```

rake routes gave me the following output:

```
 shipped_order PUT    /orders/:id/shipped(.:format)      orders#shipped
        orders GET    /orders(.:format)                  orders#index
               POST   /orders(.:format)                  orders#create
     new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)              orders#new
    edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)         orders#edit
         order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)              orders#show
               PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)              orders#update
               DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)              orders#destroy
...
```

After searching and trying to find info about path helpers and routes I found the following alternate syntax, which worked:

```
<%= button_to 'Ship', [:shipped, @order], method: :put %>
```

So the question is, why did the alternate syntax work? What's going on behind the scenes?
As an aside, is this the correct way of adding actions to routes?

If it is relevant, I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.2

Thanks

Comment: There was a third answer, but whoever put it up deleted it. It also was correct, that I could get the correct result by shipped_order_path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By nesting the `PUT` `shipped` route within your resource route, you are effectively declaring that there is a `shipped` action on the `Order` controller. Actions are performed on models, and to that extent, the Rails naming convention for `link_to` helpers is `action_controller` (e.g., `new_post_path`).

Running `rake routes` yields the following:

```
# rake routes
shipped_order PUT    /orders/:id/shipped(.:format)      orders#shipped
```

To invoke the route, you can utilize the syntax that you're using:

```
<%= button_to 'Ship', [:shipped, @order], method: :put %>
```

This bracketed syntax understands the `:shipped` symbol to be the action, and `orders_controller` to be the controller. It therefore composes the same route that would be created using the path helper:

```
<%= button_to 'Ship', order_shipped_path(@order), method: :put %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first one you're giving the button_to the route_path but not the resource specific path. The correct way would be to do

```
order_shipped_path(@order)
```

The route needs to resolve the :id portion and the helper can only do that when the specific object is passed to it.

```
shipped_order PUT    /orders/:id/shipped(.:format)      orders#shipped
```

In your second case you're telling it both the route, :shipped, and the resource, @order.